# psql export query output to a new table in a new sqlite3 db

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

Using `psql` we can export a query output to a csv file.

```
psql -d somedb -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 -c "\COPY (select * from sometable )  TO 'sometable.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;"
```

However I need to export the query output to a new table in a new sqlite3 database.

I also looked at `pg_dump`, but haven't been able to figure it out a way with it.

The reason I want to export it as a new table in a new sqlite3 db without any intermediately CSV conversion is because

1. The query output is going to run into GBs, I have disk space constraints - so rather than csv export and then create a new sqlite3 db, need to get this in one shot

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using the standard INSERT SQL statements.

It's required the same table scheme. The `grep` command removes the problematic characters, such as `--` or blanklines.

```
pg_dump --data-only --inserts --table=sometable DBNAME | grep -v -e '^SET' -e '^$' -e '^--' | sqlite3 ./target.db
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: helpful - I gave it an initial shot using the command `pg_dump -U postgres --data-only --inserts --table=\"myPgTable\" myPgDb | grep -v -e '^SET' -e '^$' -e '^--' | sqlite3 ./mySqlite3Db.db` -  it throws a few error lines `Error: near line 8: near "SET": syntax error` however I see `mySqlite3Db.db` size keep on increasing - can't say if this is foolproof as the process is very slow - running for more than an hour with only 4MB of data exported - source table has ~75 million records - any idea to improve speed ? The `pg_dump` command output is pasted here -  https://pastebin.com/rP4bStcb